# Access a required controller's properties from a template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive `foo` inside a directive `container`. The DOM hierarchy looks like this:

```
<container>
  <foo></foo>
</container>
```

I can use `require: '^container'` in my `foo` in order to access it from my `link` function. However, I often want to access that controller from inside a template, so I have to set the controller on the scope in my `link` function, and it gets pretty repetitive. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: Apparently I was too vague. Here's an example:

```
mod.directive('container', function() {
  return {
    controller: function() {
      this.interesting = "foo";
    }
  };
});
mod.directive('foo', function() {
  return {
    require: '^container',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ct) {
      scope.ct = ct; // this is the annoying line
    }
  };
});
```

With the template like this:

```
{{ ct.interesting }}
```

Obviously having that line in there isn't the end of the world, but it makes me think that I'm doing something wrong. Is there a better design?

Comment: What exactly is repetitive? Can you give an example that you think is redundant?

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. What does `set controller on scope in link` even mean?

Comment: I added an example to the question.

Comment: Could be you are over using `require`. Don't need it all the time , particularly if scope isn't isolated. If not isolated scope,  directive has same scope as the parent.

Comment: If you don't have isolated scope, I guess you can attach all such properties to scope instead of controller's instance.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include it in the example, but I *am* using isolated scope. I'd prefer to keep doing so if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the controller as feature that was added to Angular 1.2 is for.

```
mod.directive('container', function() {
  return {
    controller: function() {
      this.interesting = "foo";
    },
    controllerAs: "ct"
  };
});
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work -- perhaps because of isolated scopes, which I didn't mention in the question (sorry about that, I use them on *everything*, so I'm not used to having to explicitly say that).

Comment: Yes, the isolation is the issue. Isolating a scope means that nothing outside of that directive can access it and in the DOM you have the parent scope available for that element. If you are not storing internal values on the scope that you want to keep hidden and make not accessible then don't use isolated scopes, as there is not need, and it will make your life easier. If you want to make a copy of the scope and add new values consider using `scope: true` instead